# Calculate the sum of values within an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops

I am trying to find the total sum for each item sold inside an array, like so:

The array looks like this:

```
 [ 
  {
    'Some Title Item', '22', 'Apple'
  },
  {
    'Another Item', '12', 'Android'
  },
  {
    'Third Item', '15', 'Android'
  }, 
  {
    'Another Item', '6', 'Apple'
  },...
]
```

I already have a variable were I store all the titles/labels, and now need to find the sum of total items sold for each of those.

Comment: The outer array should probably use `[]` not `{}`

Comment: The example doesn't make much sense. Ignoring the invalid syntax... Where do the numbers in the _"desired output"_ come from? And where did `'Apple'` and `'Android'` go?

Comment: If you want to group based on a column: [Sum of same nested array data using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67345005) and [Iterate over multi-dimensional array and return aggregated sum based on first index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50240545) and [Summing a 2D array by “group”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34678309)

Comment: Thank you all for the time and suggestions! the below answer actually worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input and output must be arrays.

Use `array.reduce` for achieve your desired result.

```js
const data = [
  [
    'Some Title Item', '22', 'Apple'
  ],
  [
    'Another Item', '12', 'Android'
  ],
  [
    'Third Item', '15', 'Android'
  ],
  [
    'Another Item', '6', 'Apple'
  ]
];
let output = [];
output = data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const node = acc.find((node) => node[0] === curr[0]);
  if (node) {
    node[1] += Number(curr[1]);
  } else {
    acc.push([curr[0], Number(curr[1])]);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(output);
```